# unable to view silverlight based sites -Your current security settings do not allow this file to be downloaded

Tags: silverlight

I am trying to browse silverlight.net from a fresh windows2008 machine

I try to download the silverlight plugin displayed in the above site, instead the error message below is shown.

> Error: Your current security settings
>   do not allow this file to be
>   downloaded.

I tried adding the site to trusted zone as well but no use

Is there anyother tweak I need to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Server 2008 comes *very* locked down.  Way too much so, in my opinion.  My first recommendation would be to download and install Chrome, which is a much better browser all around, and then go from there.  But that aside, you can also try:

Try this (from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsxps/thread/749f394f-f248-45c6-a258-55ee99ac50f7)):

Open Internet Explorer browser
- Go to Tools menu
- Select Internet Options
- Go to Security tab
- Select Internet zone
- Click on "Custom level..."
- Under Downloads category, enable the option "File download"
- Under Miscellaneous category, select Prompt (recommended) for the option "Launching applications and unsafe files"
- Under Miscellaneous category, select Prompt (recommended) for the option "Launching programs and files in an IFRAME"
- Validate the changes by clicking on OK
- Leave the Internet Options
- Close the browser
- Re-open it, this issue should be fixed ^^

Answer (score 0):

Arcgis.com also uses SilverLight. It complains "This application requires you to update your browser with the Microsoft Silverlight plugin. Click here to update." The update link seems to be valid, and works after applying Ken Smith's answer from 31Jan, but downloads a 32-bit version under IE 11.0.9600.17207, under Win 8.1 x64. The installer says a newer version is already installed, and aborts. After restarting IE, back to the same complaint at arcgis.com.

Clearly IE under Limited User acct has some additional setting(s) that need tweaking. IE under Admin acct works fine accessing arcgis.com .

Via:  www.iegallery.com/Addons/Details/644, tried "Add to Internet Explorer", but nothing happened.  JavaScript must be enabled.

However, even after getting to a place where the valid version of SilverLight will download, the install fails, because "the same version is already installed". So IE under a Limited User acct is Still w/Out SilverLight plug-in...